# GoogleDeveloperConsoleにて課金処理の脆弱性に関する警告アラートを解消したい

Tags: android, unity3d

現在GooglePlayにてアプリを配信していますが
7/22からGoogleDeveloperConsoleにて下記のようなセキュリティアラートが表示されるようになりました
アプリの該当箇所を修正してこのセキュリティアラートを解消したいのですが、できなくて困っております

```
アプリで使用中のアプリ内課金の実装が正しくありません。詳しくは、Google ヘルプセンターのこちらの記事をご覧ください。

脆弱性が含まれているクラス:

com.google.android.gms.internal.dx
com.google.android.gms.internal.eb
com.prime31.util.IabHelper

APK のバージョン 48、47 に影響します。
```

Googleヘルプセンターの記事↓
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7054270

Googleヘルプセンターの記事に書いてあるようにアプリのiabHelperを更新するように書かれているので、それを含むprime31を更新すれば良いのだと思い
prime31を最新版にアップデートしたり
少し無理やりですがUnity5用のprime31をダウンロードしてiabHelperを含むjarファイルを取ってきてプロジェクトの同名ファイルに上書きしたりしてGoogleDeveloperにアップロードしてみましたがアラートが解消できない状態です

何か知っていることがあれば情報を共有して頂ければ幸いです

よろしくお願いします

開発ツール:Unity4.6.9p4
課金処理:prime31を使用